# Global variable for Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, global-variables, ejs

I'm using Node Express with EJS. I have a Login module which does all user session related jobs (like for login- generate token, Verify token). So in app.js before sending request to particular module I call login->controller->verifyToken

```
// app.js
const user = require('./controllers/login');
app.use('/dashboard', user.verifyToken,  dashboard);
app.use('/network', user.verifyToken, network);
```

user.verifyToken - verifies the token from request header and gives me user details like name, profile pic, etc. I want to store these user details in a Global variable so that I can access it in all the pages. So I did this.

```
userHeader = authData.user; // without var, let
```

But with this I can access variable at view files (.ejs). But I cant access this variable at other module .JS files. I think reason behind this is that all view files are executed afterwards, whereas .js files get executed at the time of 'require'.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Do this with sessions like `req.session.userHeader = authData.user;` Then you will have this object in your `req.session`.

Comment: use `express-session` to store the global variable

Comment: I can use `req.session` but this will not work on both the places. It will work for module files (.js) but will not work on EJS files (because I cant access req in EJS files). To access the value in EJS I have to call it at JS files and pass it as argument.
I was searching and found that there some global variables (not very sure about it).

Comment: But you can send parameters to ELS file, like this : `app.get('/', function(req, res){
 let userParam = "John Smith"; 
    res.render('index',{user:userParam});
});` userParam get data from session

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing right now. I have around 25+ modules and each module has many requests (like /pageno, /list, /detail, etc), so I have to make changes to all those to make this work. That's why I was thinking about Globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done to overcome my problem. I have used both session and a variable

```
userHeader = authData.user;

res.cookie('userHeader', userHeader, {
    maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 3 hours
});
```

I'm using userHeader variable directly on ejs files and on other Node modules files I'm getting userHeader variable from response cookie first and then using it.